# loop flv inside flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm new in Flash and I need to insert a flv into a new flash project and I want that video to play non-stop.

thanks

---

this is interesting, but if i use a smaller video, then the video is looping...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the FLVPlayback component, the code to loop your video should look like this:

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent;

/**
* Your code where you set the source and other properties of the FLVPlayback component
*/

//Add an event listener to the COMPLETE event, so you will know when the video reached the last frame
flvComp.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, loopVideo);

//Rewind and start playing the video again
function loopVideo(event:VideoEvent):void
{
    flvComp.autoRewind = true;
    flvComp.play();
};
```

I hope it helps, good luck
Rob

Comment: it stil doesn't work. I have a movieclip going on and it includes this flv movie.. the movieclip works, but the movie stops after it's time is up. this codes gives me an error at "VideoEvent". i tried writing just video..

Answer (score 1):

[here's an example with a looped flv](http://wonderfl.net/c/3dVV), you need almost only `NetConnection`, `NetStream` and `Video` there